# How to I make `unwrap_or` to return a vector of zeroes?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a struct with an `Option<Vec<...>>`, and at some point need to produce either data contained in it, or an array of zeroes in the case of `None`. I've tried multiple approaches but I always get stuck with a compile error. How should I code the `bar` function?

```rust
pub struct Foo {
  pub data: Option<Vec<u32>>
}

impl Foo {
  fn bar(&self) -> &Vec<u32> {
    self.data.as_ref().unwrap_or_else(|| &vec![0, 10])
  }
}

fn main() {
  let foo = Foo { data: None };
  println!("{:?}", foo.bar());
}
```

```
> rustc main.rs
error[E0515]: cannot return reference to temporary value
 --> main.rs:7:42
  |
7 |     self.data.as_ref().unwrap_or_else(|| &vec![0, 10])
  |                                          ^-----------
  |                                          ||
  |                                          |temporary value created here
  |                                          returns a reference to data owned by the current function

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0515`.
```

Comment: The problem is not the `Vec`, it's the reference.

Comment: Someone needs to own the "default" value. You can store the default vector of zeroes in `Foo` as a private field to be returned by reference, or you can return a [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html). You also probably want to return a slice, not a `Vec`. An immutable reference to a `Vec` is narrower and provides no benefits over an immutable slice.

Comment: Nit: `vec![0, 10]` is an array containing a `0` and a `10`. If you want an array of ten zeroes then you need a semicolon: `vec![0; 10]`

Answer (score 2):

As others have indicated, returning a slice is preferable for other reasons, but it also makes the implementation of this method easier -- you can just take a slice of a static array:

```
pub struct Foo {
  pub data: Option<Vec<u32>>
}

impl Foo {
  fn bar(&self) -> &[u32] {
    self.data.as_deref().unwrap_or(&[0; 10])
  }
}

fn main() {
  let foo = Foo { data: None };
  println!("{:?}", foo.bar());
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fda5bc514a1335c19d84949ceab13543))

Comment: [No need to create a `static`, static promotion kicks in](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ce8bde7a2488edc9f88df91f5b8ec0ce).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Ah right, for some reason I couldn't get that to work at first. Not sure what I did wrong.